# Comparing two unsorted text files to find intersection file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two text files. One is a set of frequencies I receive using an RTL SDR. These frequencies are avilable in my surrounding region. The other is a database of all registered frequencies in the region. I aim at finding the unregistered frequency.
My database is:

```
ARFCN:  987, Freq:  927.6M, CID: 36233, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -37
ARFCN:  989, Freq:  928.0M, CID: 57501, LAC:  7716, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -45
ARFCN:  992, Freq:  928.6M, CID: 58531, LAC:  7716, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -42
ARFCN:  994, Freq:  929.0M, CID: 36231, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -31
ARFCN:  995, Freq:  929.2M, CID: 36232, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -39
ARFCN:  999, Freq:  930.0M, CID: 47081, LAC:  7716, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -36
ARFCN: 1004, Freq:  931.0M, CID: 36231, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -31
ARFCN: 1008, Freq:  931.8M, CID: 47103, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -37
ARFCN: 1010, Freq:  932.2M, CID: 40691, LAC:  7716, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -48
ARFCN: 1011, Freq:  932.4M, CID: 47102, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -50
ARFCN:    1, Freq:  935.2M, CID: 13013, LAC: 10421, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -65
ARFCN:    2, Freq:  935.4M, CID: 30889, LAC: 10421, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -60
ARFCN:    3, Freq:  935.6M, CID: 30928, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -45
ARFCN:    3, Freq:  935.6M, CID: 33272, LAC: 10421, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -65
ARFCN:    6, Freq:  936.2M, CID: 10096, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -27
ARFCN:   10, Freq:  937.0M, CID: 30911, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -47
ARFCN:   25, Freq:  940.0M, CID: 14429, LAC: 51136, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -44
ARFCN:   49, Freq:  944.8M, CID: 15535, LAC: 52207, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -27
ARFCN:   51, Freq:  945.2M, CID: 12408, LAC: 51136, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -46
ARFCN:   54, Freq:  945.8M, CID: 35535, LAC: 52207, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -49
ARFCN:   56, Freq:  946.2M, CID: 25535, LAC: 52207, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -51
ARFCN:   58, Freq:  946.6M, CID: 12941, LAC: 51136, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -35
ARFCN:   60, Freq:  947.0M, CID: 18662, LAC: 51136, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -58
ARFCN:   62, Freq:  947.4M, CID: 32941, LAC: 51136, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -52
ARFCN:   64, Freq:  947.8M, CID:  7673, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -43
ARFCN:   66, Freq:  948.2M, CID: 10001, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -27
ARFCN:   68, Freq:  948.6M, CID: 12941, LAC: 51136, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -50
ARFCN:   70, Freq:  949.0M, CID: 15132, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -34
ARFCN:   71, Freq:  949.2M, CID:  5373, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -44
ARFCN:   75, Freq:  950.0M, CID:  6561, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -45
ARFCN:   79, Freq:  950.8M, CID: 10003, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -48
ARFCN:   82, Freq:  951.4M, CID: 10002, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -34
ARFCN:   86, Freq:  952.2M, CID:     0, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -57
ARFCN:  117, Freq:  958.4M, CID: 20096, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -28
ARFCN:  119, Freq:  958.8M, CID: 12549, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -41
ARFCN:  120, Freq:  959.0M, CID: 30096, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -31
ARFCN:  122, Freq:  959.4M, CID: 33783, LAC: 10421, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -42
ARFCN:  124, Freq:  959.8M, CID: 42549, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -33
```

Whereas my received frequency file is:

```
Script started on 2020-07-19 14:55:19+0500
linux; GNU C++ version 7.3.0; Boost_106501; UHD_003.010.003.000-0-unknown


ARFCN: 1004, Freq:  931.0M, CID: 36231, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -34
ARFCN: 1008, Freq:  931.8M, CID: 47103, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -30
ARFCN:    6, Freq:  936.2M, CID: 10096, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -27
ARFCN:   10, Freq:  937.0M, CID: 30911, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -33
ARFCN:   49, Freq:  944.8M, CID: 15535, LAC: 52207, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -28
ARFCN:   56, Freq:  946.2M, CID:     0, LAC:     0, MCC:   0, MNC:   0, Pwr: -50
ARFCN:   66, Freq:  948.2M, CID: 10001, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -27
ARFCN:   79, Freq:  950.8M, CID: 10003, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -43
ARFCN:   82, Freq:  951.4M, CID: 10002, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -36
ARFCN:  100, Freq:  955.0M, CID:   667, LAC:  1007, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -27

Script done on 2020-07-19 14:58:05+0500
```

It can be seen that both lists are unsorted. Now intend to create a new text file or atcleast just an output on ubuntu terminal such that the frequency present in my current frequency list but not in the database is displayed. So far I've been unable to find a hack. I have written a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh
clear
echo "                      */\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\*/\* "
echo "                      C O N F L I C T I N G   A R F C N s "
echo "                      *\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/*\/* "
echo UNIQUE BTS TOWERS ARE


import bitarray
r = bitarray.bitarray(5000000000)

for line in open(alpha.txt):
    r[int(line)] = True

for line in open(Database.txt):
    if r[int(line)]:
        print line
#set(open(alpha.txt)) & set(open(Database.txt))
#sort Database.txt alpha.txt | uniq -u
#comm -3 alpha.txt Database.txt
#   Print lines in alpha.txt not in Database.txt
#words1 = set(open("Database.txt").read().split())
#words2 = set(open("alpha.txt").read().split())

#duplicates = words1.intersection(words2)
#uniques = words1.difference(words2).union(words2.difference(words1))

#print "Duplicates(%d):%s"%(len(duplicates),duplicates)
#print "\nUniques(%d):%s"%(len(uniques),uniques)


echo "The scan GSM frequencies are collected"
notify-send "COLLECTED!"
echo DONE!
```

I've tried all these alternatives but none of them really work.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Python?

Comment: It's pretty conficting: the file starts as shell script `#! /bin/sh`, then continues as Python (Python 2 - because of the print statements) and the question is marked as Python3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple GNU awk that does what (I think) you are trying to do:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} NR==FNR{db[$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6]; next}
        $1~/ARFCN: / && !($1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 in db)' db.txt rec.txt
```

Prints:

```
ARFCN:   56, Freq:  946.2M, CID:     0, LAC:     0, MCC:   0, MNC:   0, Pwr: -50
ARFCN:  100, Freq:  955.0M, CID:   667, LAC:  1007, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -27
```

This works by comparing the first 6 fields and ignoring `Pwr` since that might be variable depending on conditions.

If all fields are relevant, you can simplify to:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} NR==FNR{db[$0]; next}
       $1~/ARFCN: / && !($0 in db)' db.txt rec.txt
```

Prints:

```
ARFCN: 1004, Freq:  931.0M, CID: 36231, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -34
ARFCN: 1008, Freq:  931.8M, CID: 47103, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -30
ARFCN:   10, Freq:  937.0M, CID: 30911, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -33
ARFCN:   49, Freq:  944.8M, CID: 15535, LAC: 52207, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -28
ARFCN:   56, Freq:  946.2M, CID:     0, LAC:     0, MCC:   0, MNC:   0, Pwr: -50
ARFCN:   79, Freq:  950.8M, CID: 10003, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -43
ARFCN:   82, Freq:  951.4M, CID: 10002, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -36
ARFCN:  100, Freq:  955.0M, CID:   667, LAC:  1007, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -27
```

Or if you only want to compare the `ARFCN` field:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} NR==FNR{db[$1]; next}
        $1~/ARFCN: / && !($1 in db)' db.txt rec.txt
ARFCN:  100, Freq:  955.0M, CID:   667, LAC:  1007, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -27
```

You get the idea...

Comment: hey how would i go about if I have two entries with same values, say same ARFCN. How would i ammend the code to single that one out?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your question

Comment: okay so the received data i have, lets suppose that we have two rows and both have the same ARFCN (for example 25). I want guidance with a code that will give in the output an instance where both entries with ARFCN 25 will show. I hope I am more clear now.

Comment: I can further simplify it by saying that suppose I have a text file. **a,b,c** and in the next line **b,a,c** and the next line **b,c,d**. Now I want to compare only the first column. In the first case, a is different to b so we're good to go. But in the next line, b is same as b in the third line. so I want to print these two line.

Comment: It is really a new question. I think you would get a better answer if you came up with a good example of input, desired output, and correctly tag if you want Python or awk solutions.

Comment: I was wondering if you could guide me incase I want an opposite case. How would I change my code if I want to print all entries present in the database file?

Answer (score 0):

```
db = open('Database.txt', 'r') 
dbLines = db.readlines()
alpha = open('alpha.txt', 'r') 
alphaLines = alpha.readlines()
output=[line for line in alphaLines if line not in  dbLines and line.startswith('ARFCN') ]
```

Output:

```
    ['ARFCN: 1004, Freq:  931.0M, CID: 36231, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -34\n',
 'ARFCN: 1008, Freq:  931.8M, CID: 47103, LAC:  7713, MCC: 410, MNC:   4, Pwr: -30\n',
 'ARFCN:   10, Freq:  937.0M, CID: 30911, LAC: 10470, MCC: 410, MNC:   1, Pwr: -33\n',
 'ARFCN:   49, Freq:  944.8M, CID: 15535, LAC: 52207, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -28\n',
 'ARFCN:   56, Freq:  946.2M, CID:     0, LAC:     0, MCC:   0, MNC:   0, Pwr: -50\n',
 'ARFCN:   79, Freq:  950.8M, CID: 10003, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -43\n',
 'ARFCN:   82, Freq:  951.4M, CID: 10002, LAC:   470, MCC: 410, MNC:   6, Pwr: -36\n',
 'ARFCN:  100, Freq:  955.0M, CID:   667, LAC:  1007, MCC: 410, MNC:   3, Pwr: -27\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.  Takes the intersection of two sets of lines.  Prints them.

```
print(*(set(open('alpha.txt')) & set(open('Databse.txt'))), sep='')
```

This works as long as both of your files fit in memory.

Comment: It gives out the following error. bash: syntax error near unexpected token `*(set(open('alpha.txt')) & set(open('Databse.txt'))),'

Comment: @mosterup: That's because you're running it as a bash script (which is a different language).  Look up how to run Python on your platform.